# One toggled image displayed at a time

Tags: jquery

In a Joomla page I have icons which when clicked toggle an image. This is the jQuery script (courtesy of guradio "Toggling between icon and larger image with transition" - April12 '16):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('img.do_things').on('click', function(evnt) {
    var image_path = jQuery('p#image_path').html(),
      image1_src = image_path.substring(0, 26) + 'scene_icon' + '.png',
      elementId = evnt.target.id,
      image2_src = image_path + elementId + '.png',
      origsrc = jQuery(this).attr('src'),
      src = '';
      origsrc === image1_src ? src = image2_src : src = image1_src;      //toggle between the src
      jQuery(this).fadeOut(800, function() {
        jQuery(this).attr('src', src);      //set src
      }).fadeIn(1200);
  });
});
```

The html for the image path is:

```
<p id="image_path">/templates/beez_20/images/doing_things/</p>
```

At present, any images that are displayed remain displayed whether or not other icons are clicked. So it is possible that in a page with 5 icons, 5 images can be displayed simultaneously.  I want to change this so that only one image is displayed at any one time. I've tried to work out the logic for this using variables as flags, but with no success. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function that converts an image back to its icon form:

```
function make_icon(img) {
    var image_path = jQuery('p#image_path').html(),
      src = image_path.substring(0, 26) + 'scene_icon' + '.png';
    if (img.attr('src') != src) {
        img.fadeOut(800, function() {
            img.attr('src', src);
        }).fadeIn(1200);
    }
}
```

And call it on all the other images.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('img.do_things').on('click', function(evnt) {
    var image_path = jQuery('p#image_path').html(),
      image1_src = image_path.substring(0, 26) + 'scene_icon' + '.png',
      elementId = evnt.target.id,
      image2_src = image_path + elementId + '.png',
      origsrc = jQuery(this).attr('src'),
      src = '';
      origsrc === image1_src ? src = image2_src : src = image1_src;      //toggle between the src
      jQuery('img.do_things').not(this).each(function(i, img) {
        make_icon($(img));
      });
      jQuery(this).fadeOut(800, function() {
        jQuery(this).attr('src', src);      //set src
      }).fadeIn(1200);
  });
});
```

Comment: This script removes the icons too. I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I want the icons to remain because they control the display of the images. I only want i image displayed at any one time with the icons all visible. Thanks

Comment: Instead of changing the `src` of the images, it would be easier to have two images `<img class="image" src="imagename.png"><img class="icon" src="iconname.png">`. To switch between image and icon you hide one and show the other. Then if you want to hide all the images, you can do `$(".image").hide()`.

Comment: I don't quite follow when you say "hide one and show the other" could you please suggest the form of the code for this. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: `$(".icon").click(function() { $(this).hide(); $(this).prev(".image").show(); })`

Comment: Actually, modifying the html as suggested would be impractical as there are 20 pages (articles) with 4 images per page. Only html for the icons appears these pages. The images are in a directory, as indicated by the html reference above. It would be much preferable to modify the existing jQuery script.

Comment: Then write a function that you can call on an image, and it checks whether the `src` is the icon or the full image, and switches to the icon. Similar to the function in your click handler. Then call it on all the other images with `$('img.do_things').not(this).each()`

Comment: I've checked the code in Firebug and stepping thru it, it drops out at the make_icon function. up until then OK.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `make_icon($(img))`

Comment: It works!! Many thanks, Barmar, I'm grateful for your help :) best regards